# css3 resize bubbling + onresize

Tags: css, resize

I realise I cannot use css3 resize with IE or Opera but that is OK. The two problems I have do not seem to have been really addressed in stackoverflow  so far. The div with the resize style contains two levels of nested divs. I don't want the resize handles on the inner divs. After resizing, the whole thing is regenerated to fill the outer div's new size:- with more/less or bigger/smaller columns/rows depending on what edge is dragged. Please open the Labs tag on my [web site](http://glasier.hk) if not clear.